# Take groups of 5 strings from List

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a `List<string>` and I want to take groups of 5 items from it.  There are no keys or anything simple to group by...but it WILL always be a multiple of 5.

e.g.

```
{"A","16","49","FRED","AD","17","17","17","FRED","8","B","22","22","107","64"}
```

Take groups of:

```
"A","16","49","FRED","AD"
"17","17","17","FRED","8"
"B","22","22","107","64"
```

but I can't work out a simple way to do it!

Pretty sure it can be done with enumeration and Take(5)...

Comment: You can indeed use Take(5) and on the next iteration Skip(5).Take(5) and so on.

Comment: This works for small lists, but in general is a bad idea. It iterates over the collection once per group leading to quadratic running time [O(n^2)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/487300/141397). This applies to all the other answers here using `.Skip().Take()`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419019/split-list-into-sublists-with-linq

Comment: @3dGrabber: i have tested the `GroupBy` + the `Skip` approaches on a very large list(`for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)list.AddRange(list);`. The `GroupBy` took 23 seconds whereas the `Skip` is still running after 10 minutes ;)

Comment: @3dGrabber: do you mean this version? `... .GroupBy(x => x.index / 5)`

Comment: I've stopped it after 20 minutes, i'm afraid that it would eat my PC otherwise. @BlueChippy: The morelinq `Batch` should be the most efficient apporach but the `GroupBy` is ok. 3dGrabbe was referring to the `Skip.Take` approaches which are really slow if the list is getting large.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the integer division trick:

```
List<List<string>> groupsOf5 = list
    .Select((str, index) => new { str, index })
    .GroupBy(x => x.index / 5)
    .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.str).ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: this will work but, 1) it will create unnecessary anon. objects, 2) it will iterate over the collection at least three times.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419019/split-list-into-sublists-with-linq yeah, right

Answer (score 8):

```
 List<List<string>> result = new List<List<string>>();
 for(int i = 0; i < source.Count; i += 5 )
      result.Add(source.Skip(i).Take(5).ToList());
```

Like this?

Comment: This has terrible runtime performance, see my comment in the question.

Comment: you did not specify how long this list is nor what you want to do with this data. this solution is therefor a simple way how to do it. if you specify what you want to do with the data we can provide a more detailed and more performant solution

Comment: this is perfect

Answer (score 3):

In common programming syntax:

```
     public List<List<string>> Split(List<string> items, int chunkSize = 5)
     {
         int chunkCount = items.Count/chunkSize;
         List<List<string>> result = new List<List<string>>(chunkCount);

         for (int i = 0; i < chunkCount; i++ )
         {
             result.Add(new List<string>(chunkSize));
             for (int j = i * chunkSize; j < (i + 1) * chunkSize; j++)
             {
                 result[i].Add(items[j]);
             }
         }

         return result;
     }
```

It's `O((N/ChunkSize) x ChunkSize)` = `O(N)`, that is linear.

Comment: throws index out of range exception

Comment: Best answer so far IMO.
Since the chunk size is constant inside the loop you could use an array instead, which is faster and uses less memory. Or at least use the list constructor with 'initial capacity', so the list does not have to resize itself.

Comment: @3dGrabber, Unless you need something from the bench of functionalities that the List ships with, Array is faster. I'm not aware of the use cases, and List seams to be more universal in modern development.

Comment: Always go for O(n), that trumps elegance every day, in every way. +1 for that!

Comment: Yeah, linear algorithms do scale.

Comment: @Andrew: sure, array or list is debatable. But `result.Add(new List<string>(chunkSize))` would still make sense.

Comment: Yes, there's internal array behind the scenes. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [`Batch`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Batch.cs?r=f85495b139a19bce7df2be98ad88754ba8932a28) method from `MoreLINQ` library:

```
var result = list.Batch(5).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Take() and Skip() to achieve this:

```
        List<string> list = new List<string>() { "A", "16", "49", "FRED", "AD", "17", "17", "17", "FRED", "8", "B", "22", "22", "107", "64" };

        List<List<string>> result = new List<List<string>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count / 5; i++)
        {
            result.Add(list.Skip(i * 5).Take(5).ToList());
        }
```

Comment: I don't know how many total sets of 5 there will be, just that they will be complete sets

Comment: edited to work for yoy

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function:

```
public IEnumerable<string[]> GetChunk(string[] input, int size)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (input.Length > size * i)
    {
        yield return input.Skip(size * i).Take(size).ToArray();
        i++;
    }
}
```

it returns you chunks from your list

you can check it like

```
var list = new[]
{
    "A", "16", "49", "FRED", "AD", "17", "17", "17", "FRED", "8", "B", "22", "22", "107", "64"
};

foreach (var strings in GetChunk(list, 5))
{
    Console.WriteLine(strings.Length); 
}
```

Comment: Like this answer because I can extend to set the "chunk" size...

Comment: I've edited it to support different chunk sizes

Answer (score 1):

If you need performance or cannot use linq cause of your .net version here is a simple solution with `O(n)`

```
    private List<List<string>> SplitList(List<string> input, int size = 5)
    {
        var result = new List<List<string>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Count; i++)
        {
            var partResult = new List<string>();
            while (true)
            {
                // save n items
                partResult.Add(input[i]);
                if ((i+1) % size == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
                i++;
            }
            result.Add(partResult);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Your name speaks for itself if i look at the inner loop ;)